# How to load images in datagridview with sql and c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I am developing an application with C#
I have a database with table called Resuktats with 6 fields:

```
logo_imageA -> teamA -> scoreA -> scoreB -> teamB -> logoB
```

The field logo_Image stores the image path in my hard drive

An example of a record would be:

```
C:\imageA.png -- teamA -- 2 -- 3 -- teamB -- C:\imageB.png
```

I wonder how fill a datagridview that shows the name foreach team and the result and especially - logo image for each team in my database sql.

i have trying this code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int number_of_rows = dgv_calendrier.RowCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
        {
            //DataGridViewImageColumn dataGridViewColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

                if (dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "true")
                dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells["logo_dom"].Value = 


    }
```

}

a print screen of the execution of my sql query:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, take some time to share some code pieces which describe what has been done so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem yourself, divide it in subproblems:

- If you've got a system.Drawing.Image, can you show it in your datagridView?
- If you've got the name of an image file, can you load the file as a System.Drawing.Image and thus show it in your datagrid view?

The first problem is solved by searching how to display images in a datagrid view
[How to: Display Images in Cells of the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2ab8kd75(v=vs.100).aspx)

The second: [Image.FromFile(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i have added the system.Drawing.Image in my code, and i just trying this code:
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
int number_of_rows = dgv_calendrier.RowCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
            {
                dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells["logo_dom"].Value = dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}

}

Comment: Better to edit your original question as you did. So can you load the image from the filename you get? If you create an image (new Bitmap for instance), can you show it in the datagridview? Describe what works and what doesn't work. Do you get an error message or no message at all, it just doesn't show? If you debug, if there really an image that you add to the datagridview? How did you tell the datagridview that a certain cell contains an image?

Comment: I actually started programming, I could view the data stored in the database, voila, the next step is to display the logo instead of the path of each team, I started the code but I have not yet executed, I expect your support for the code in C #, I normally tell you everything, and I'll add a print screen of the execution of my sql query

Answer (score 0):

First you can load all data into datagrid from SQL Server:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

dgv_calendrier.Columns.Add(imageCol);    // Add new image columns to grid view

int number_of_rows = dgv_calendrier.RowCount;

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_rows; i++)
{
    if (dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "true")
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@" dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells["logo_dom"].Value.ToString()"); // get image location and convert to bitmap.

    dgv_calendrier.Rows.Add();
    dgv_calendrier.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = img; //set you newly added column
}
```

Hope this will help